# Count for regex is returning 0 instead of current count

Tags: python

If I have a

pattern "A*C" and my
string is "AKKLSKLCAajaklDAajdklafdC" it should return 2 but it returns 0.

```
string = input("What is the string?")
pattern = input("What is the pattern?")

print (len(re.findall(pattern,  string)))
```

I've also tried

```
count = 0
match = re.search(pattern,string)
if match:
    count +=1
```

That also returned zero.

Comment: I get **2** when I run this.  I pasted your given strings in place of the **input** calls.  Check your typing, print out the variables before you use them, and see what you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things,

First, the code as given DOES return 2:

```
string = "AKKLSKLCAajaklDAajdklafdC"
pattern = "A*C"
print (len(re.findall(pattern, string)))
```

Second, are you sure "A*C" is the pattern you want to match for? That pattern is asking for zero or more consecutive A's, followed immediately by a C, so in the example string you give it's matching just the two C's (eg. "AKKLSKL**C**AajaklDAajdklafd**C**"). If you're trying to find an A followed by a C with some random junk in between (eg. "**AKKLSKLC**AajaklD**AajdklafdC**"), you want "A.*C" instead. That is because, for regular expressions, the '.' character is a wildcard, as opposed to '*' which means to look for zero or more of the preceeding character. This is different in function to how a lot of non-regex searchers work, which use '*' as the wildcard character.

Comment: I realized I wanted A.*?C

Comment: Thanks for your help and the good explanation of regex. It made it much easier for me to understand.

Comment: Sure thing! Also, this site is a great place to practice regex's [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/), as it breaks down your regex expression into its basic parts, and lets you play around with what it does or does not match.

Comment: That's really useful. Thanks so much!